# sizing a String added to a pdf file using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-reader

I have the following code :

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("doc.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
new FileOutputStream("AttestationTemp.pdf"));
PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1257, false);
over.setFontAndSize(bf, 50);
over.beginText();
ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("String"), 110, 384, 0);
over.endText();

try
{
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
    {
        File myPDF = new File("doc.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myPDF);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that when I change the size of my String using the setFontAndSize method, I get the same result (same small size), so I want to know how to set the size of the string added to the pdf file.

Comment: You are mixing calls of iText at different levels: `setFontAndSize` is  very low level where you add individual content instructions manually; at this level you would add text using `showText`. `ColumnText.showTextAligned` is part of a higher level API and creates its own font and size setting operations; at this level you select the font when creating the `Phrase` parameter.

Comment: Great. I'll make an actual answer from that comment.

Answer (score 1):

iText offers APIs for PDF content generation at different levels.

There is a very low level API of `PdfContentByte` methods. At this level you manually add individual content stream operations one-by-one, e.g.:

```
PdfContentByte over = ...;
over.setFontAndSize(bf, 50);
over.beginText();
over.setTextMatrix(110, 384);
over.showText("Hello World!");
over.endText();
```

Then there is the higher level API of `ColumnText` methods. At this level you construct and style your text using `Phrase` and `Chunk` objects and the `ColumnText` methods create the corresponding content stream operations:

```
PdfContentByte over = ...;
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("Hello World!", new Font(bf, 50));
ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, 110, 384, 0);
```

The code of the OP mixes instructions at these levels which in his case results in his font setting call to later be overridden and, therefore, ignored.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I looked it up before answering and indeed was surprised to find out that **Text state** operators (e.g. **Tf**) *are* allowed outside text objects (in contrast to **Text-showing** and **Text-positioning** operators). I believed differently before, too.